# Jackson randomly adds Type Info while serialising Collection instance variables

Tags: java, jackson

I have a web application deployed on Tomcat and using Jackson to serialise objects to JSON. At times on restart I observe that jackson suddenly starts putting type info with collections (specifically List). Its not always and generally gets fixed on tomcat restart.
Example:

```
    public class Demo implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String name;
        private List<Long> f1;

        public List<Long> getF1() {
            return f1;
        }
        public void setF1(List<?> f1) {
            this.f1 = f1;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Demo [f1=");
            for(Long f : f1) {
                sb.append(f).append(",");
            }
            sb.append("]");
            sb.append(name);
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
```

`Demo.class` and other similar classed are wrapped under a common `DataHolder.class`

```
public class DataHolder {

    @JsonProperty("v")
    private Object value;

    public DataHolder() {
    }

    public DataHolder(Object value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DataHolder [value=" + value + "]";
    }
}
```

I have written a custom object mapper as:

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        getSerializationConfig().
        setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);

        setVisibilityChecker(getSerializationConfig().
        getDefaultVisibilityChecker().
        withFieldVisibility(Visibility.ANY).
        withGetterVisibility(Visibility.NONE).
        withIsGetterVisibility(Visibility.NONE).
        withSetterVisibility(Visibility.NONE));

  configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
  .configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false)
  .configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
            enableDefaultTyping(DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT);
        }
```

The main logic to invoke the above classes and serialise them is:

```
CustomObjectMapper ct = new CustomObjectMapper();
DataHolder dh = new DataHolder(d);
String jsonToWrite = ct.writeValueAsString(dh);
```

Now the two different JSONs are generated randomly as:

```
{"v":["com.main.cache.Demo",{"name":"piyush","f1":[1130890999009]}]}
```

OR

```
{"v":["com.main.cache.Demo",{"name":"piyush","f1":[["java.lang.Long",1130890999009]]}]}
```

I.e `java.lang.Long`randomly gets into the JSON and gets fixed on restart.

How to solve this.

Edit: I am also looking if I can find a custom serializer/de-serializer which just eliminates the `JSONTypeInfo` in all cases for all the collection references in `Demo.class`

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to remove this line:

```
enableDefaultTyping(DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT)
```

It's a Jackson's option which adds a type information when needed. You can read more about it in [Jackson's Java Docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#enableDefaultTyping(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping)). Generally you can pass the below options to this method:

> - **JAVA_LANG_OBJECT** This value means that only properties that have Object as declared type (including generic types without explicit type) will use default typing.
> - **NON_CONCRETE_AND_ARRAYS** Value that means that default typing will be used for all types covered by OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE plus all array types for them.
> - **NON_FINAL** Value that means that default typing will be used for all non-final types, with exception of small number of "natural" types (String, Boolean, Integer, Double), which can be correctly inferred from JSON; as well as for all arrays of non-final types.
> - **OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE** Value that means that default typing will be used for properties with declared type of Object or an abstract type (abstract class or interface).

Comment: But if I do that then I lose the `com.main.cache.Demo` info as well so the new output is : `{"v":{"name":"piyush","f1":[1.13089105E12,1131.0]}}`

Comment: Try setting `DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL` as a parameter. Since the Long class is final, it should not be included in the output.

Comment: But I also want to support the cases where I can have a `List` of a `Custom.class` in `DataHolder.java`. So on a broad way I want to get the JSONTypeInfo of object if I am serializing Collections or Maps but if I have collections or Maps within my `DataHolder.java`, then I don't want JSONTypeInfo

Comment: Let me understand you. So you want a type info to be included in the output **only** for the `com.main.cache.Demo` class. For all other cases the type info should be omitted. Am I right? If so, you can disable the default typing, and explicitly annotate the `Demo` class so it will include the type info. `@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.CLASS, include=As.WRAPPER_ARRAY)`

Comment: Correction: I want some annotation or custom (de)serializer which can allow me to explicitly enable or disable type info for any collection/Map declared in `com.main.cache.Demo`

Comment: For enabling you have already mentioned above `@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.CLASS, include=As.WRAPPER_ARRAY)` , can you also help me with how can I explicitly disable it for a field in class.

Comment: `@JsonTypeInfo` can be also put on a field declaration. If you disable the default typing and put this annotation on a desired field, only this field shall has a type information included. If you want to use this annotation to disable the type info for a specified field, put this on a declaration and set the property _use_ to `Id.NONE`.

Comment: I tried using `@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NONE, include=As.WRAPPER_ARRAY)` but its not working.

Comment: Try without the `include` parameter. If still displaying, try adding another annotation: `@JsonDeserialize(as=NoType.class)`.

Comment: I tried: `@JsonDeserialize(as=NoType.class)
    @JsonSerialize(as=NoType.class)
    private List<?> f1;` but its also not working, also posting the field declaration.

Comment: As this conversation is already long, plz post your solution as another answer. Also thanks a lot for helping me out. The exception I am getting is: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Illegal concrete-type annotation for method 'f1': class javax.lang.model.type.NoType not a super-type of (declared) class java.util.List (through reference chain: com.mmt.admin.hotels.cache.model.DataHolder["v"])

Comment: But did you try simply `@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NONE)`? Put it on a field or on a getter.

Comment: So just to be clear, I have `enableDefaultTyping(DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT);` enabled as I want the type info for other lists and have explicitly put `@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NONE)` on `private List<?> f1;` to disable its type info. But its not working.